# Cannot resolve symbol 'createFromResource'

Tags: android

I'm completely confused as to what this means. Ive done some searching but so far havent found any help.

I'm using android studio and have a dialog fragment I'm setting up a spinner in

```
 Spinner systemFontSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.system_font_spinner);
 ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.system_fonts, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 systemFontSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

createFromResource is highlited in red and when I hover it it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'createFromResource'"

my array

```
<resources>
<string-array name="system_fonts">
    <item>Helvetica</item>
    <item>Helvetica-Neue</item>
    <item>Impact</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/system_font"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/system_font_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Remove `new` before your ArrayAdapter. It's a static method

Comment: Pedro, put your comment as an answer so it can be selected as correct. Before I do and take all your glory ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just so Spidy don't take all the glory :)

You're calling a static method that will return you an arrayadapter so you shouldn't be using `new` because you're not instantiating anything.

You should be doing it this way:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.system_fonts, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource(android.content.Context, int, int)

Now I shall take all the glory :)

Comment: Just for clarity to other folks, the code for creating ArrayAdapter, setting drowpdown view resource and setAdapter() should go inside onCreate() method (if you are using an activity).