# Getting NullpointerException when to get JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception

When im trying to get the json data with an api request. Ill get a NullPointerException.

```
public CouchPotatoMovie(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    this.title = json.getString("title");
    this.status = json.getString("status");
    this.id = json.getString("_id");
    this.info = new CouchPotatoMovieInfo(json.getJSONObject("info"));
    if(json.getJSONArray("releases").length() != 0)
    {
        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("releases");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        {
            releases.add(new Release(array.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my constructor. Im gettin an null pointer at `releases.add(new Release(array.getJSONObject(i)))`

```
10-15 18:10:49.233: E/AndroidRuntime(9609): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 18:10:49.233: E/AndroidRuntime(9609):     at 
nl.somename.model.couchpotato.CouchPotatoMovie.<init>(CouchPotatoMovie.java:31)
10-15 18:10:49.233: E/AndroidRuntime(9609):     at 
nl.somename.model.CouchPotato.parse(CouchPotato.java:229)
10-15 18:10:49.233: E/AndroidRuntime(9609):     at 
nl.somename.model.CouchPotato.available(CouchPotato.java:106)
```

The JSON im getting is (Sorry I don't know how to put breaks in it):

```
{"status": "active", "info": {"rating": {"imdb": [6.4000000000000004, 29064]}, "actor_roles": {"Rebecca Ferguson": "Ergenia", "Rufus Sewell": "Autolycus", "John Hurt": "Cotys", "Irina Shayk": "Megara", "Tobias Santelmann": "Rhesus", "Ian McShane": "Amphiarus", "Reece Ritchie": "Iolaus", "Ingrid Bols\u00f8 Berdal": "Atalanta", "Aksel Hennie": "Tydeus", "Dwayne Johnson": "Hercules"}, "tmdb_id": 184315, "plot": "Fourteen hundred years ago, a tormented soul walked the earth that was neither man nor god. Hercules was the powerful son of the god king Zeus, for this he received nothing but suffering his entire life. After twelve arduous labors and the loss of his family, this dark, world-weary soul turned his back on the gods finding his only solace in bloody battle. Over the years he warmed to the company of six similar souls, their only bond being their love of fighting and presence of death. These men and woman never question where they go to fight or why or whom, just how much they will be paid. Now the King of Thrace has hired these mercenaries to train his men to become the greatest army of all time. It is time for this bunch of lost souls to finally have their eyes opened to how far they have fallen when they must train an army to become as ruthless and blood thirsty as their reputation has become.", "tagline": "", "release_date": {"dvd": 0, "expires": 1413562699, "theater": 1406239200, "bluray": false}, "original_title": "Hercules", "genres": ["Action", "Adventure"], "via_imdb": true, "mpaa": "PG-13", "images": {"disc_art": [], "poster": ["https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/d3gL1VX7FwhJ5iNAax2tEcchfN0.jpg", "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ4ODA5MTA4OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjMyODM5MTE@._V1_.jpg", "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ4ODA5MTA4OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjMyODM5MTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"], "extra_thumbs": [], "poster_original": ["https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/d3gL1VX7FwhJ5iNAax2tEcchfN0.jpg"], "landscape": [], "actors": {"Rebecca Ferguson": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/dbIS4S32rrIJyEysx7huT6ZAmjN.jpg", "Rufus Sewell": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/f2PNMnztHluTOw8YfCJUZ2pKfbe.jpg", "John Hurt": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/rpuH2YRLpxJjMxHq4T1QdOSVtlN.jpg", "Irina Shayk": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/lZGbyk3dHkxWPo0kqxJLNo25APn.jpg", "Tobias Santelmann": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/sCtnswOiS203HyXTzlDesvEI4mj.jpg", "Ian McShane": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/pY9ud4BJwHekNiO4MMItPbgkdAy.jpg", "Reece Ritchie": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/7zUVjsbIxPkmBNf7DYXH1kR1QVy.jpg", "Ingrid Bols\u00f8 Berdal": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/raEPYKXAe6NP0m3WUyJDh7PQUR3.jpg", "Aksel Hennie": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/fEmgeaFbhzOSBRqe2mO6sa1EaSp.jpg", "Dwayne Johnson": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/n432vxKiMpgdCmOjq7UX6Gatisa.jpg"}, "backdrop_original": ["https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5CdgKsD4Rg87XIXmQSSomod5VCH.jpg"], "clear_art": [], "logo": [], "banner": [], "backdrop": ["https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/5CdgKsD4Rg87XIXmQSSomod5VCH.jpg"], "extra_fanart": []}, "directors": ["Brett Ratner"], "titles": ["Hercules", "Hercules: The Thracian Wars", "Hercules - Il guerriero"], "imdb": "tt1267297", "year": 2014, "via_tmdb": true, "actors": ["Dwayne Johnson", "Ian McShane", "John Hurt", "Rufus Sewell"], "writers": ["Ryan Condal (screenplay)", "Evan Spiliotopoulos (screenplay)", "Steve Moore (Radical comic \"Hercules\")"], "runtime": 99, "type": "movie", "released": "2014-07-25"}, "_t": "media", "releases": [{"status": "ignored", "info": {"size": 0, "protocol": "nzb", "description": "Verenigde Staten<br>Actie / Avontuur<br>99 minuten<br><br>geregisseerd door Renny Harlin<br>met Kellan Lutz, Liam McIntyre en Richard Reid<br><br>Een jonge legerkapitein (Liam McIntyre) wordt een goede vriend van Hercules (Kellan Lutz), de zoon van de oppergod Zeus. Maar nadat een slechte koning hen misleidt, worden Hercules en de kapitein in slavernij verkocht en moeten ze zij aan zij vechten om hun vrijheid terug te verdienen.<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Container: Mp4<br>Quality: 720p<br>Formaat: x264<br>Audio: Ac3 standaard <br>Language: English<br>Subtitles: Nederlands<br>Size: 756.86 MB<br><br>Geschikt voor alle soorten tv&amp;#39;s en tablets.<br><br>Deze eigen upload  heb ik encrypted geplaatst wegens notice and takedown.<br><br>Onder de downloadpijl zit een DUMMY NZB.<br><br>GEBRUIK ONDERSTAANDE LINK VOOR DE GOEDE NZB :<br><br>=====================<br><a href=\"http://bit.ly/1fAJf3V\">http://bit.ly/1fAJf3V<\/a><br>=====================<br><br>Veel kijkplezier.<br /><font color=\"#ca0000\">Door: karma (bElkFg)<\/font>", "url": "http://somename.nl/spotweb/api?t=get&id=zyRjtpRGKFIFzBbUwK91l%40spot.net&apikey=", "age": 170, "name_extra": "karma", "id": "zyRjtpRGKFIFzBbUwK91l@spot.net", "score": 11, "provider": "Newznab", "seed_time": "", "provider_extra": ", somename.nl", "detail_url": "http://somename.nl/spotweb/", "type": "movie", "seed_ratio": "", "name": "The Legend of Hercules (2014) 720P NL SUBS k-a-r-m-a verzoekje"}, "_id": "ab57eccca61940eb93fcc62777bbb9c6", "media_id": "77bea2dd23d649ca99b0bb5e3875222b", "_rev": "0003b524", "_t": "release", "is_3d": false, "last_edit": 1413210234, "identifier": "36abef91c978724a30e2739d2f25d108", "quality": "720p"}], "title": "Hercules", "_rev": "004cccea", "profile_id": "12e5762bf0fb4db3a85544c83e487537", "_id": "77bea2dd23d649ca99b0bb5e3875222b", "tags": ["recent"], "last_edit": 1413073002, "category_id": null, "type": "movie", "files": {"image_poster": ["/usr/local/couchpotato/var/cache/4d48972a70c175170d3b65b0521f9afa.jpg"]}, "identifiers": {"imdb": "tt1267297"}},
```

Comment: Did you initialize releases? Like `new ArrayList<Release>();`?

Comment: @Timmeeh93 Can you paste the complete trace? I need to see how does the control reachs `nl.somename.model.CouchPotato.available(CouchPotato.java:106)`

Comment: @PedroOliveira *FACEPALM* Thank you so much! i've been searching for this problem for over an hour now.

Comment: @Amal problem is already solved, like Pedro Oliveira said, i forgot to initialize the arraylist

Comment: Great to hear that! @Pedro's comment deserves an upvote!

Comment: @PedroOliveira : why don't u post it as answer. I saw many post u only comments although that is the correct answer [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350158/cannot-resolve-symbol-createfromresource/26350321#26350321)

Comment: @kaushik No need to post an answer when the problem is this simple :)